# Как определить координаты значков на рабочем столе?

Tags: python, windows

Мне надо получить координаты и название каждого значка на рабочем столе.

То есть, например, где корзина: в левом верхнем, правом нижнем углу или вообще посередине экрана

Comment: Что вы самостоятельно накопали и какая часть вопроса вызывает трудности?

Comment: Нашел как определить количество и всё

Comment: Наберите в поисковике «как вывести список всех файлов из директории пайтон»

Comment: На первую часть вопроса поможет pyautogui.

Comment: Я просил не расположение в файловой системе(то есть путь к файлу), а именно на экране рабочего стола

Comment: Объясните свой вопрос, что значит "определить расположение файла на экране рабочего стола"?

Comment: @Danila что конкретно вам непонятно? Вы не в курсе, что на рабочем столе файлы можно двигать?

Comment: По теме вопроса, возможно, поможет что-нибудь отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039190

Comment: @andreymal ты просто чудо